# how to show the current build with c# or msbuild?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, msbuild, azure-devops

I created an asp.net mvc4 application and I have setup continuous integration and deployment to windows azure.

Because I have configured it to build after checkin, it would be very useful to print somewhere in the application which build is using.

I guess there should be a way with c# and msbuild api if it exists, which is the current build.

something like:  FullStackSampleApplication_20130413.2

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

I found this line:

**Update1:**
I added this to AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]

string version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

This line is printing 0.0.0.0

Comment: What are you using as your build server?

Comment: team foundation service, I saw its possible to get the version with c#, I guess it will print the assembly version? maybe what I need to do is that TFS changes the assembly version before building?, but how?

Comment: You would probably need to do a pre-build edit of the AssemblyInfo.cs. Not sure how to do this so I won't add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate new build number and revision on each build, add to your AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

The generated numbers will be based on build time. Build number will be the number of days since 2000, and revision number will be the number of  seconds since midnight/2.

Comment: pls see the update, I did that, but the assembly is always printed as 0.0.0.0

Comment: If you have multiple assemblies, you should add this attribute to all of them. Also, for troubleshooting purporse, you can just check assembly and file version via file properties/details in windows explorer. And make sure that attribute is defined only once for each assembly.